# How do I adjust my rigidbody velocity on a local axes?

Tags: unity, c#, physics, rigidbody, first-person-shooter

I have an fps rigid body script, code listed here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    [SerializeField] Camera cam;
    [SerializeField] float camSpeed;

    float yaw;
    Vector3 direction;

    Rigidbody myrigbody;
    void Start()
    {
        myrigbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        cam.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(-Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * camSpeed, 0, 0));

        yaw = (yaw + Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * camSpeed) % 360f;

        direction = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), myrigbody.velocity.y, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        myrigbody.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Euler(0, yaw, 0));
        myrigbody.velocity = direction;
        

    }
}
```

The particular part I'm having trouble with is the last line: `myrigbody.velocity = direction;`This code is moving my character perfectly, except that it doesn't adjust to my rotation in game.  If i rotate 90 degrees to the right in game, and press forward, I will move to the left (from the players perspective), I will move in the same direction when i press forward (or any other direction) no matter how I have rotated.  How do I alter the rigid bodies velocity while taking into account how the player has rotated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Vector3 worldDirection = transform.TransformVector(localDirection};
```

...will map a direction in an object's local space to the corresponding direction in world space, factoring in the object's rotation while ignoring its translation and scale. It's equivalent to:

```
Vector3 worldDirection = transform.rotation * localDirection;
```

or

```
Vector3 worldDirection = rigidbody.rotation * localDirection;
```

As an aside, you don't need to cache stick inputs in Update to apply them in `FixedUpdate`. You can just put the code that reads the analog stick values in `FixedUpdate` directly to simplify your code. Don't do that for instantaneous inputs like button presses/releases/taps, but it's safe for continuous inputs like analog stick deflection and button holds.

Comment: Thanks, the code works now, but I'm confused about how it works.  I must be misunderstanding how your conversion is affecting the direction.  How did converting it to world space fix it? I was under the misunderstanding that having a vector in world space would cause a problem like this, because world space is static and doesn't move with the player.

Comment: btw, thanks for the tip on analog stick inputs in fixed update.

Comment: Physics is computed in world space. So if you send it a velocity of (0, 0, 1), that means "Move in the direction of world z+" no matter which way your character is facing. By multiplying by your character's rotation, you apply the character's facing direction to that vector, translating it into a world space version that changes whenever the player's rotation changes. So if I'm rotated 90° right, then `transform.rotation * (0, 0, 1) = (1, 0, 0)`, correctly turning my movement in the world to point along the x+ axis instead of z+.

Comment: I understand it now, thanks for your help!